# P2P connection over wi-fi hotspot getting connected for same carrier but not for different carrier

Tags: p2p

**P2P connection:**

a) Over 3G network (both devices are on same operator), devices are unable to punch hole due to symmetric NAT.

b) However when I create hotspots using 2 devices (both devices are on same 3G operator) and connect other 2 devices to them, P2P is getting establish.

c) Also, if I take sim cards of different operator in case (b), P2P is NOT getting establish.

**Can somebody explain why in case (b) devices are able to connect but not in case (c)?
Should not (b) also face same issue of symmetric NAT?**

Comment: So I tried to connect 2 devices connected to 2 different Wi-Fi. And devices failed when one wi-fi was behind firewall. Through logs i found out that issue was that firewall was changing port (NAT).

Answer (score 0):

So I tried to connect 2 devices, connected to 2 different Wi-Fi. And failed when one wi-fi was behind firewall. I found out that issue was firewall, which was changing port (NAT).

May be carriers/operators put NAT thing when sending message to other operator/carrier. Due to which devices connect when SIM of same operator and not when of different carrier.

-Saur

[so I can't edit my comment after 5 mins...and I have lot to add. Also seems, "Enter" does not work in comments. So answering my own question. ]